# Restful service Request Source Not Available

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey

I am trying to develop a basic **Restful service** using **Jersey Maven** and **Eclipse**.

I am following the example given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/).

I followed the steps as given in the link but when I try to run the project I get a `Request Resource Not available` error.

This is my modified dependency in pom.xml file

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

and modified Build in pom.xml

```
<finalName>maven.secondrest</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
            <port>9999</port>
            <path>/</path>
                <warFile>${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The web.xml is very much the same as given in the example:

```
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>rest.model</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is altered java code:

```
package rest.model;
//imports
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
    String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
}
```

I am trying to run it by using: **mvn tomcat:run**

When I enter **localhost:9999** it displays a message "Hello World". But when I enter the url as given in the example I get a resource not found error.

This is the url I run: **http://localhost:9999/maven.secondrest/rest/hello/nelo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems like I was using the URL incorrectly. The correct URL to access this service would be **localhost:9999/rest/hello/nelo**. That is, leaving out the project name as it has already been mentioned in the plugin.

Comment: As a matter of fact I am not totally aware as to how this plugin actually accesses the resource. Any suggested reading material,regarding it working, would be greatly appreciated.